# Use Expression in Value of FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I use fast report 4.15 in delphi xe2,
How can I use Expression in Value when report get value event?

Example:

I have one MemoView in report with Text "[a]" and GetValue event of report is:

```
procedure TForm1.rep1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);
begin
  if VarName = 'a' then
    Value := 'first with [b] item'
  else if VarName = 'b' then
    Value := 'second';
end;
```

I want report: "first with second item".

**Example 2:**

in report i have one TfrxMemoView with text "[MyExp]",
in form is one EditBox with Name "edt1" which user can write text to this.

GetValue event of report is :

```
procedure TForm1.rep1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);
begin
  if(VarName = 'a1') then
    Value:= 'item 1'
  else if VarName = 'a2' then
    Value:= 'item 2'
  else if VarName = 'a3' then
    Value:= 'item 3'
  else if VarName = 'a4' then
    Value:= 'item 4'
  else if VarName = 'a5' then
    Value:= 'item 5'
  else if VarName = 'a6' then
    Value:= 'item 6'
  else if VarName = 'MyExp' then
    Value:= edt1.Text;
end;
```

Now : if i write in edt1 : "show [a2] ok" , then i want frxReport write "show item 2 ok" in frxMemoView.
if i write in edt1 : "show [a5] ok" , then i want frxReport write "show item 5 ok" in frxMemoView.
...

Comment: Can you use `Value := Format('first with %s item', ['second']);` in FastReport?

Comment: @KromStern , no , i want tfrxreport replace expression which send by `Value` in GetValue event.

Comment: Please add an example of how the code should behave? I have a suspicion this is not FastReport problem, but just a general Pascal programming trouble.

Comment: this is a fastreport question. in my code, first MemoView convert "[a]" to "first with [b] item" , but i want convert again expression "[b]" to "second". In other words i want MemoView call again GetValue to convert expression in expressions which sanded to it. this is simple code of my problem with fast report and not want replace text.

Comment: Please add an example of how the code should behave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer :

if name of frxMemoView is Memo1 then in main block of report code write :

```
Memo1.Text:= <MyExp>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question literally, this is how you can solve it with a **recursive** call to the function:

```
procedure TForm1.rep1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);
var
  Temp: Variant;
begin
  if VarName = 'a' then
  begin
    // Call the function with 'a' and get the Value into the Temp variable
    rep1GetValue('b', Temp);

    // Assemble the resulting value
    Value := 'first with ' + Temp + ' item'
  end
  else if VarName = 'b' then
    Value := 'second';
end;
```

Unless further clarification of what you want to achieve - I can't answer any better.

Comment: i think you not worked with fast report yet, using "a" and "b" is for example and in my program is other letters and not fixed.

Comment: You won't get any better answer if you refuse to provide any more details.